# How to use Addfields in MongoDB C# Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation

Mongo DB's Aggregation pipeline has an "AddFields" stage that allows you to project new fields to the pipeline's output document without knowing what fields already existed.

It seems this has not been included in the C# driver for Mongo DB (using version 2.7).

Does anyone know if there are any alternatives to this? Maybe a flag on the "Project" stage?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1750. Read the resolution "won't fix". The reasoning is given, but it's clearly not on the roadmap at all. If you really want it then specify the pipeline manually with `BsonDocument` builders since that's all the API methods actually do anyway. And/Or vote up the JIRA issue, and with sufficient backing then maybe someone will think it worth considering for future work.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure all the `BsonDocument` usage is required.  Certainly not in this example where I append the textScore of a text search to the search result.

```cs
        private IAggregateFluent<ProductTypeSearchResult> CreateSearchQuery(string query)
        {
            FilterDefinition<ProductType> filter = Builders<ProductType>.Filter.Text(query);
            return _collection
                .Aggregate()
                .Match(filter)
                .AppendStage<ProductType>("{$addFields: {score: {$meta:'textScore'}}}")
                .Sort(Sort)
                .Project(pt => new ProductTypeSearchResult
                {
                    Description = pt.ExternalProductTypeDescription,
                    Id = pt.Id,
                    Name = pt.Name,
                    ProductFamilyId = pt.ProductFamilyId,
                    Url = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pt.ShopUrl) ? pt.ShopUrl : pt.TypeUrl,
                    Score = pt.Score
                });
        }
```

Note that `ProductType` does have a `Score` property defined as

```cs
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public double Score { get; set; }
```

It's unfortunate that `$addFields` is not directly supported and we have to resort to "magic strings"

Comment: The `BsonIgnoreIfNull`d `Score` property is not needed if you only need it for further "magic string" operations.

Comment: You can always use "Set", which is a synonym for "addFields" AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

As discussed here [Using $addFields in MongoDB Driver for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305776/using-addfields-in-mongodb-driver-for-c-sharp) you can build the aggregation stage yourself with a BsonDocument.

To use the example from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/

```
{
  $addFields: {
    totalHomework: { $sum: "$homework" } ,
    totalQuiz: { $sum: "$quiz" }
  }
}
```

would look something like this:

```
BsonDocument expression = new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement>() {
    new BsonElement("totalHomeWork", new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$sum", "$homework"))),
    new BsonElement("totalQuiz", new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$sum", "$quiz")))
});
BsonDocument addFieldsStage = new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$addFields", expression));
IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> aggregate = col.Aggregate().AppendStage(addFieldsStage);
```

expression being the BsonDocument representing

```
{
  totalHomework: { $sum: "$homework" } ,
  totalQuiz: { $sum: "$quiz" }
}
```

You can append additional stages onto the IAggregateFluent Object as normal

```
IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> aggregate = col.Aggregate()
    .Match(filterDefintion)
    .AppendStage(addFieldsStage)
    .Project(projectionDefintion);
```